# Understanding PCA from the perspective of eigenspaces

Tags: pca, svd, eigenvalues

This question is from the perspective of a student who has only a fundamental idea of eigenvectors and eigenspaces (and linear algebra in general). If my understanding is correct, an eigenvector E of a vector V projects the vector V along the direction of itself by a factor of the associated eigenvalue (lambda).

```
Av = (lambda)v
```

Now, in PCA we try to find the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix of a dataset. I am unclear as to the purpose of this step: what is the practical interpretation of this? A covariance matrix cannot be interpreted as a vector, but maybe a set of vectors.

Comment: The context in your question would suggest that you should review the concept of eigenvectors. The covariance matrix is symmetric, and therefore has an eigenvector *decomposition*: http://www.visiondummy.com/2014/04/geometric-interpretation-covariance-matrix/

Comment: Several hundred posts are related to [PCA eigenvectors](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=PCA+eigenvector): please have a look.  It might help conceptually to be more careful with your language: *vectors* do not have eigenvectors: only matrices or linear transformations do.  PCA does more than find eigenvectors of the covariance matrix--indeed, finding those eigenvectors is merely an algorithm for carrying out part of a PCA.  Refer to the SVD for more information.